# How to automate adding titles and device frames to android screenshots?

Tags: android, google-play

What are the options for adding titles and device frames to android screenshots in an automated fashion?

fastlane frameit works for iOS screenshots, but what options are there for android?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On March 4 2020 [my pull request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/15087) which adds Android support to frameit was approved and merged. It is available since fastlane 2.143.0.

Comment: is there any support for framing 10 inch Android devices in frameit?